# Tab bar's navbar stuck under custom navbar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uitabbarcontroller

I am implementing a custom nav bar for much of my application, but transition to a tab bar based navigation paradigm for other portions of the app.

When I switch to the tab bar portion of the app and navigate to the "More" section of the tab bar controller, the navbar that has the "edit" button of the more section is obscured by my custom navbar.

[image]

I have tried removing my navbar from the view, bringing the tab bar's navbar to the top of the view, etc.

The goal here is to gain access to the edit button's functionality in order to rearrange icons on the tab bar.

I'd like to either invoke the edit functionality of the tab bar programmatically or bring the tab bar's navbar to the front of the view.

Thanks in advance!